# Actually there is in error in this code but if I remove (!= 1) from the code I am getting unexpected results. But the logic is same.. Please explain

Tags: python-3.x, passwords

#The question is to determine weather the password is weak or strong..

#Strong password must have at least 2 numbers,2 symbols and 7 alphabets

```
passstr = input()
nc = 0
sc = 0
ln = 0

dnm = "0123456789"
dsc = "!@#$%&*"
ln = len(passstr)
for c in passstr :
  if dnm.find(c) != -1:
     nc += 1
  elif dsc.find(c) != -1:
     sc += 1
if (nc>=2) and (sc>=2) and (ln >= 7):
  print("Strong")
else:
  print("Weak")
```

Comment: Can you clarify? ``if dnm.find(c) != -1:`` and ``if dnm.find(c):`` are *not* logically equivalent.

Comment: Those would only be equivalent if -1 were falsey and 0 were true, but they're the opposite. If you want to check for -1, you need to explicitly check for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised code:

```py
passstr = input()
nc = 0
sc = 0
ln = 0

dnm = "0123456789"
dsc = "!@#$%&*"
ln = len(passstr)

for c in passstr:
    if c in dmn:
        nc += 1
    elif c in dsc:
        sc += 1

if nc>= 2 and sc >= 2 and ln:
  print("Strong")
else:
  print("Weak")
```

You could also make `dnm` and `dsc` sets to make membership testing (slightly) faster. Doesn't really matter here but if you were doing this on a few hundred thousand passwords it might make a difference.